# Access SCOPE_IDENTITY() in CodeBehind C# TSQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql, azure

I'm trying to retrieve `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and place it in a parameter I can access in codebehind.  My .aspx:

```
<asp:sqldatasource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myString %>"
    insertcommand="INSERT INTO [CountyHelp](County,City)
    VALUES (@County,@City) ;SELECT @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()">
    <insertparameters>      
          <asp:formparameter name="County"  formfield="County" />
          <asp:formparameter name="City"  formfield="City" />
          <asp:parameter Direction="Output"  Name="Id" Type="Int32" />             
    </insertparameters>
```

Then access it in this code behind:

```
protected void btn_send_Click(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    string sID = e.Command.Parameters["@Id"].Value.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    Response.Redirect("documentsnew.aspx?id=" + sID);
}
```

Maybe it is my button code is not sending the parameter value:

```
     <asp:button
       id="Button1"
       runat="server"
       text="Add Help"
       onclick="btn_send_Click" 
       />
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: I get this error: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'btn_send_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: is this the click event for a button?

Comment: I'm currently using this for the Output parameter as well with no luck: <asp:Parameter Direction="Output"  Name="Id" Type="Int32" />

Comment: You can't use `SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs` for a button click event.

Comment: Yes it is the button click event.

Comment: Ahh ok.  How can I access it then?

Comment: Change it to `EventArgs` and reference the `SqlDataSource` object directly: `SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Id"].Value.ToString()`?

Comment: Put the error message in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are using the wrong EventArgs for your button Click event. Use a regular EventArgs for the Click event and then see what happens.

You could grab the Scope_Identity by handling the SqlDataSources Inserted event
so

```
<asp:sqldatasource
id="SqlDataSource1"
OnInserted ="On_Inserted"
runat="server"
connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myString %>"
insertcommand="INSERT INTO [CountyHelp](County,City)
VALUES (@County,@City) ;SELECT @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()">
<insertparameters>      
      <asp:formparameter name="County"  formfield="County" />
      <asp:formparameter name="City"  formfield="City" />
      <asp:sessionparameter Direction="Output"  Name="Id" Type="Int32" />             
</insertparameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

then

```
protected void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     SqlDataSource1.Insert();

}

protected void On_Inserted(Object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) 
{
    string sID = e.Command.Parameters["@Id"].Value.ToString();
      Response.Redirect("documentsnew.aspx?id=" + sID);
}
```

Comment: I started out that way but just got NULLs in the QueryString but I'll try again now.

Comment: @KyleGMotion Edited my answer. Try this approach and see if it works for you

Comment: I'm getting this error with that code:  CS0122: 'SendMail.On_Inserted(object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @KyleGMotion change private to protected for the On_Inserted event and let me know if that works

Comment: thanks for educating me about OnInserted it will be very valuable as I learn more.

Comment: @KyleGMotion Glad to hear it :)